# Rails app generating parameterized URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-url

I'm taking saas class and while doing the homework 2, the rails app generates parameterized URLs like http://localhost:3000/movies?sort=title.
However other URLs on the page are like http://localhost:3000/movies/new or http://localhost:3000/movies/1. I'm wondering why the sorting is not resolved as a restful URL like /movies/sort/title.
And when do we create restful URLs and when to use parameterized URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST (as used by Rails) operates on resources. Specifically it uses the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to operate on resources.

Assume you had a movie model. You might have a movies resource which would define the following routes:

```
GET '/movies' - Gets a list of movies
GET '/movies/new' - Gets the form to create a new movie
POST '/movies' - Creates a new movie
GET '/movies/:id' - Gets the details about the movie with :id
GET '/movies/:id/edit' - Edits the movie with :id
DELETE '/movies/:id' - Deletes the movie with :id
PUT '/movies/:id' - Updates the movie with :id
```

Sorting on the other hand is a way of providing rails with additional information regarding the request. So, if you're going to be doing the CRUD actions on a model or a resource you should be using RESTful routing ([as described by the railsguide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)) but otherwise you may want a parameter, or you could consider sorting your data client side using javascript!

Note that there isn't anything stopping you from implementing a route like `'/movies/sort/title'` it just isn't a RESTful route and requires custom routes in your `routes.rb` file. Just read the railsguide I linked above for the complete story.